# npm not installing returns error consistently

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, firefox, npm

I was trying to install this : Search git whodotheyserve. com but this error shows up consistently .No matter what i try. I have tried other version of npm they are installed but the

npm test
error shows up .

npm run-script task
too returns error

This happens consistently .Also i am following each step mentioned in source of this project.Image attached.Please help where am i wrong here. The file extension used here ls .I had no experience with these. [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxil7.png)

[Echo %PATH% image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndr8O.png)

Comment: Error is clear. You dont have python installed on your system or if installed set `PATH` variable to python executable directory.

Comment: Check if you have Python installed: `python --version`

Comment: I did so : 
<code>python --version</code><code>Python 3.5.1</code>

Answer (score 2):

**The build fails because you are using Windows instead of Linux.**

This is clearly stated in the installation instructions you claim to have followed in your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153408/npm-install-error-though-python-already-included/35154055#35154055).

> ## [notes](https://github.com/dizzib/WhoDoTheyServe.com#notes)
>
> The build tasks rely on Linux shell commands such as pkill and rsync
>   so are unlikely to run on other OS's without some tweaks.

If you want to run this under windows, you should ask the repo maintainer for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install python 2.7 and make sure it's in your PATH variable.

Try:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\python2.7\python.exe
```

Replace C:\python2.7\python.exe with your actual python installation path

Comment: OS is Linux not windows

Comment: I did the same: No the error is npm is not recognised as an internal or external command.OS is Windows

Comment: @7171u os is clearly windows. Look at the paths in the screenhots

 Can you post the output of echo %PATH%

Comment: Image link attached for echo %PATH%

Comment: Yeah. My Bad. Didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that this was made to run on linux only.So ,it won't run on windows on which i was trying to run it.The issue arose as i was trying to install it on wrong OS.I have successfully installed it on linux.It works great.

I want to thank all those who contributed in helping me with this issue.Thanks a lot to all those who helped.