# npm install error though Python already included

Tags: python, node.js, git

I was trying to install [whodotheyserve.com](https://github.com/dizzib/WhoDoTheyServe.com#build-and-run-locally-) but this error shows up consistently, no matter what I try. I have tried other version of npm they are installed but the `npm test` error shows up.

`npm run-script task` too returns error.
It is metioned that it wont run on windows but is there a way to run it on windows.
This happens consistently. Also I am following each step mentioned in source of this project. Image attached. I have added Python as mentioned here:

[image: link image].

Comment: Yup guessed it right as no 1 was replying there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The build fails because you are using Windows instead of Linux.**

This is clearly stated in the [installation instructions](https://github.com/dizzib/WhoDoTheyServe.com#notes) you claim to have followed.

> ## notes
>
> The build tasks rely on Linux shell commands such as pkill and rsync
>   so are unlikely to run on other OS's without some tweaks.

If you want to run this under windows, you should ask the repo maintainer for guidance.

Comment: okay thanks this might help

Comment: @Lucky, don't forget to mark this as the answer to your question.

Comment: I will mark as soon as  i get a possible solution to run it on windows

Comment: I successfully installed it on linux.Now my issue is resolved.

Comment: I tried it on ubuntu works fine